# Install macOS, Linux, Windows in the same USB External SSD

Tags: macos, windows, dual-boot

I have a `960GB` External USB SSD and I have MacBook Air.

I would like to know if is it possible to install, **macOS Catalina** `320GB`, **Windows 10** `320GB`, **Linux CentOS 7** `320GB` in the same External HD.

I don’t know how to find a guide to know how to install these sequentially.

Comment: Windows does not like to boot from an external drive.

Answer (score 1):

You should be possible to install, macOS Catalina 320GB, Windows 10 320GB, Linux CentOS 7 320GB in the same external SSD. ***You probably will have to use the CLI to install Windows 10 to the external SSD.***

Below is a suggested GPT partitioning for the drive.

1. `EFI` for macOS Catalina and CentOS 7
2. `Apple_APFS` for macOS Catalina
3. `EFI` for Windows 10
4. `Microsoft Basic Data` for Windows 10
5. `Microsoft Basic Data` for  CentOS 7
6. `Linux LVM` for CentOS 7

I would suggest creating partitions 1 through 4 before installing any operating systems. Leave free space where partitions 5 and 6 will eventually reside. Next, install macOS followed by Windows 10. Finally, install CentOS. Here, I would let CentOS create its own partitions (5 and 6) in the free space.

I do not know what your experience is with respect to installing operating systems. I can expand on this answer if necessary.